# Java to DB2 Connection

Tags: java, db2

I'm trying to connect to DB2 from JCreator. I have ClassPath Environment variable set to :

> .;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc4.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\sqlj.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\common.jar;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip

`Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")` throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

I am using windows 7 64 bit.

Please help!

Comment: Is that the system CLASSPATH variable?  Make sure that's included in the JVM's classpath.  The JVM doesn't automatically pick it up.

Comment: You also have to understand the content of the different jars and zip for java. Normally you only need C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc4.jar and C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar

Comment: Yes it is system ClassPath variable. I'm not used to configuring settings, how exactly do I point JVM to the DB2Driver path?

Comment: It seems to be working after adding path to the driver on JDK profile. Thanks alot for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Please post all stackTrace. Common situation is, that class is not in jar! Open your jar with driver and check, if class is there. I check it for you. db2jcc4.jar contains db2jcc4.jar\COM\ibm\db2\jcc\DB2Driver. But the COM is Capital letters. Try use -cp or just copy jar with db driver to same foler closed to your app.